# Clarification on Docker status

Tags: docker, docker-container

When I run a `hello-world` container, it prints the message and exits. The status of the container will then be marked as `Exited` If I start the container again, the message do not get printed.

But when I run a `nginx` container and stop the container, the status will be changed to `Exited`. If I start the container again using the `start` command, the `nginx` process starts again. How is the behavior different.

```
 docker run hello-world

 docker container ls --all
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS                  NAMES
1dcd009d1fd3        hello-world         "/hello"                 15 seconds ago      Exited (0) 13 seconds ago                          focused_pike
```

Comment: What are your `hello-world` container Dockerfile and `CMD` ? The `nginx` container behaves according to standards.

Comment: @MichéeLengronne updated the question with output of the command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you start the exited container it is by default *not* attached to the stdout / stdin of the process. You can see the output in two ways:

1. You can attach to the container to see the output using the `--attach` or `-a` option to the `start` command like: `docker start -a 1dcd009d1fd3`
2. You can view the output using the `logs` command such as: `docker logs 1dcd009d1fd3`

Comment: Does that mean that the exited container is same as the stopped container?

Comment: Yes, except process exited instead of being stopped with the `stop` command.

Comment: Good to know. I never used a container interactively and never restarted a container (always run them from their image) so I never noticed the difference.